# using select statement in then clause of case

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to include select statement in the `then` of `case` statement but the output is not as expected. I know there is different method to do this but can it be done the way i'm trying to do.

Using the following example data:

```
create table example(name varchar(10));

insert into example values
('abc'),('bcd'),('xyz');
```

I have tried this query (here is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366db9/6)):

```
select 
case when ((select * from example where name='abc')>=1)
then (select * from example where name='abc')
else (select count(*) from example)
end
from example
```

But it outputs

```
3
3
3
```

Expected output if `name='abc'` exist

```
name
abc
```

if not the `count(*)`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subquery in the example is `(select * from example where name='abc')` which is a result set, not a scalar value. Currently it "works" because it is comparing the only column in the table to the value `1` but if you had more than one column in the table it would error out. Perhaps you intended `(select count(*) from example where name='abc')`?

Similarly, the THEN clause in a case can only be used to provide a single column value. In order to do this, perhaps you meant the following:

```
select 
    case when exists (select * from example where name='abc')
              then (select name from example where name='abc')
         else (select count(*) from example)
    end
from example
```

But even here you will get three rows and there is no correlation between the rows in `example` and the result set, so I am not really sure what you're trying to do. I imagine there is a higher purpose though so I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
select distinct
case when ((select count(name) from example where name='abc')>=1)
then (select * from example where name='abc')
else (select count(*) from example)
end
from example
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**:
For the query, you are trying, the `from example` in the last will cause to loop through all the records and fetch all the records. To restrict that, you have to remove that.

**Point 2**:

You can't combine multi row `select *` in a `true` condition with a single row `count(*)` in a `false` condition. You should `limit` to `select` a single row.

***Example***:

```
select 
  case when ( select count(*) from example where name='abc' ) >= 1
            then ( select * from example where name='abc' limit 1 )
            else ( select count(*) from example )
        end as name
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to bother with the complex queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct 
FROM example 
GROUP BY name = 'abc' 
ORDER BY name = 'abc' DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

If you really want to use CASE just for the sake of using it:

```
SELECT 
   CASE name 
      WHEN 'abc' THEN 'abc' 
      ELSE 'others' 
   END AS name, COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM example 
GROUP BY name = 'abc' 
ORDER BY name = 'abc' DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, which will work even you enter a second duplicate row as value 'abc'. Mostly above suggested queries will not work as you enter this duplicate row while as per your query condition (>=1), there can be multiple rows for name as 'abc'.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN b.cnt>=1 
THEN a.name 
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EXAMPLE) 
END 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM EXAMPLE WHERE NAME='abc') a 
JOIN (SELECT NAME,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM EXAMPLE WHERE NAME='abc') b 
ON a.name=b.name
```